# SQL Query randomly stopped working?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, union

I have an SQL query that provides information for an SSRS report. The report stopped working today and I've checked the query and its not working either. I cant see anything wrong with the query but it wont run. Any help would be much appreciated, I really need to get this report back online today, here is the error produced:

```
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Expr2522'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1172.ShortDescription" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1170.ShortDescription" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1168.ShortDescription" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.Exam" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVHigh" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVAch" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVComp" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVCont" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVFund" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVXfr" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PVStart" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PG_DifficultyOrDisabilityID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PG_EthnicityID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.PG_SexID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.ExpEndYrNumber" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tbl1166.LR_MYSID" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Col5840'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Col5843'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Col5849'.
```

Here is my query:

```
WITH All_Genders_LLDDs_Ethns as (SELECT
                                 Gender,
                                 LLDD,
                                 Ethnicity,
                                 PG_AgeBandID,
                                 AgeBand,
                                 AgeGroup

                                 FROM
                                 (SELECT 'Male' as Gender 
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 'Female' as Gender) as Genders,
                                 (SELECT 'LLDD' as LLDD 
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 'NO_LLDD' as LLDD) as LLDDs,
                                 (SELECT 'WB' as Ethnicity
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 'NWB' as Ethnicity) as Ethnicities,
                                 (SELECT DISTINCT
                                  PG_AgeBandID,
                                  ab.Description as AgeBand,
                                  ag.Description as AgeGroup

                                  FROM
                                  MSQL2.ProAchieve.dbo.LR_MYSHighByLevel l
                                  LEFT JOIN MSQL2.ProGeneral.dbo.AgeBand ab on l.PG_AgeBandID = ab.AgeBandID
                                  LEFT JOIN MSQL2.ProGeneral.dbo.AgeGroup ag on l.PG_AgeGroupID = ag.AgeGroupID

                                  WHERE
                                  l.PG_QType3ID not in ('30','40') and
                                  l.LR_MYSID in (SELECT 
                                                   Setting
                                                  FROM 
                                                  msql2.ProAchieve.dbo.SystemSetting
                                                  WHERE 
                                                  Code='DefaultLRSummary') AND 
                                  l.PG_ExpEndYrID IN ('11/12')) as AGE_Bands

                                 ),
    CoreProAchData as (SELECT
                        al.AgeBand,
                        al.AgeGroup,
                        lml.LR_MYSID,
                        al.Gender,
                        al.LLDD,
                        al.Ethnicity,
                        lml.EthnicityDetails,
                        lml.LDDetails,
                        lml.DisabilityDetails,
                        '' AS Details,
                        al.PG_AgeBandID,
                        lml.PG_ExpEndYrID,
                        lml.ExpEndYrNumber,
                        sum(lml.pvstart) as pvstart,
                        sum(lml.PVXfr) as PVXfr,
                        sum(lml.PVFund) as PVFund,
                        sum(lml.PVCont) as PVCont,
                        sum(lml.PVComp) as PVComp,
                        sum(lml.PVAch) as PVAch,
                        sum(lml.PVHigh) as PVHigh,
                        sum(lml.exam) as exam

                        FROM
                        All_Genders_LLDDs_Ethns al
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                                   CASE WHEN l.PG_AgeGroupID = '1' THEN '16-18' ELSE '19+' END as AgeGroup,  
                                   CASE WHEN l.PG_SexID = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END as Gender,
                                   CASE WHEN l.PG_EthnicityID IN ('23','31') THEN 'WB' ELSE 'NWB' END as Ethnicity,
                                   CASE WHEN l.PG_DifficultyOrDisabilityID IN ('1') THEN 'LLDD' ELSE 'NO_LLDD' END as LLDD,
                                   e.ShortDescription AS EthnicityDetails,
                                   ld.ShortDescription AS LDDetails,
                                   d.ShortDescription AS DisabilityDetails,
                                   l.*

                                   FROM
                                   MSQL2.ProAchieve.dbo.LR_MYSHighByLevel l
                                   INNER JOIN MSQL2.ProGeneral.dbo.Ethnicity e ON e.EthnicityID = l.PG_EthnicityID
                                   INNER JOIN MSQL2.ProGeneral.dbo.LearningDifficulty ld ON ld.LearningDifficultyID = l.PG_LearningDifficultyID
                                   INNER JOIN MSQL2.ProGeneral.dbo.Disability d ON d.DisabilityID = l.PG_DisabilityID

                                   WHERE
                                   l.PG_QType3ID not in ('30','40') and
                                   l.LR_MYSID in (SELECT 
                                                  Setting
                                                  FROM 
                                                  msql2.ProAchieve.dbo.SystemSetting
                                                  WHERE 
                                                  Code='DefaultLRSummary') AND 
                                   l.PG_ExpEndYrID IN ('11/12')
                                   )lml on al.Gender = lml.Gender and
                                           al.LLDD = lml.LLDD and
                                           al.Ethnicity = lml.Ethnicity and
                                           al.PG_AgeBandID = lml.PG_AgeBandID


                        GROUP BY
                        al.AgeBand,
                        al.AgeGroup,
                        lml.LR_MYSID,
                        al.Gender,
                        al.LLDD,
                        al.Ethnicity,
                        lml.EthnicityDetails,
                        lml.LDDetails,
                        lml.DisabilityDetails,
                        al.PG_AgeBandID,
                        lml.PG_ExpEndYrID,
                        lml.ExpEndYrNumber)

SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'Gender' as Stat_Type,
Gender as Grouping_Val,
'' AS Details,
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
Gender

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'Learning Difficulty'  as Grouping_Val,
LDDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
LDDetails != 'none' AND
LDDetails != 'not known/not provided'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
LDDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'No Learning Difficulty'  as Grouping_Val,
LDDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
LDDetails = 'none'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
LDDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'Unknown'  as Grouping_Val,
LDDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
LDDetails = 'not known/not provided'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
LDDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'Disability'  as Grouping_Val,
DisabilityDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
DisabilityDetails != 'no disability' AND
DisabilityDetails != 'not known/not provided'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
DisabilityDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'No Disability'  as Grouping_Val,
DisabilityDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
DisabilityDetails = 'no disability'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
DisabilityDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD Break Down' as Stat_Type,
'Unknown' as Grouping_Val,
DisabilityDetails AS Details, 
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

WHERE
DisabilityDetails = 'not known/not provided'

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
DisabilityDetails

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'LLDD' as Stat_Type,
CASE WHEN LLDD ='NO_LLDD' THEN 'No ' ELSE '' END + 'Learning Disability / Difficulty'  as Grouping_Val,
'' AS Details,
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
LLDD

UNION ALL SELECT
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
'Ethnicity' as Stat_Type,
CASE WHEN Ethnicity ='NWB' THEN 'Non ' ELSE '' END + 'White British' as Grouping_Val,
EthnicityDetails AS Details,
sum(isnull(pvstart,0)) as starts,
sum(isnull(PVXfr,0)) as transfers,
sum(isnull(PVFund,0)) as LSC_funded,
sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) as continuing,
sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) as completed,
sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) as achieved,
sum(isnull(PVHigh,0)) as highgrades,
sum(isnull(exam,0)) as exam_taken_not_know,
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvstart,0))) AS 'Success Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVComp,0)) + sum(isnull(PVCont,0)) , sum(pvstart)) AS 'Retention Rate',
ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages(sum(isnull(PVAch,0)) , sum(isnull(pvcomp,0))) AS 'Achievment Rate'

FROM
CoreProAchData

GROUP BY
--AgeBand,
--PG_AgeBandID,
AgeGroup,
Ethnicity,
EthnicityDetails) as sub

ORDER BY
--convert(int,PG_AgeBandID),
Stat_Type,
Grouping_Val
```

Comment: Impossible to say without the table structures involved. But even if you would post these I really wouldn't want to look at it. You just dumped your complete statement without the slightest effort on trying to narrow it down. -1 for "no effort shown".

Comment: i'm sorry, i've tried numerous attempts for the past 3 hours but had no success

Comment: Did you try to isolate the offending part / subquery? I don't think so. But this would be a start.

Comment: what I dont understand is why the error shows Tbl1166 instead of the table name, sorry for posting such a long query i just didnt know what else to do?

Comment: yes Ive ran the subquery alone and it runs

Comment: If all else fails, resort to [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223).

Comment: And how do you suppose we know? It is even possible that the error message is coming from a totaly different query. As I said: Impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: @Will: You say you have run *the* subquery and *it* runs. But there are *lots* of subqueries in there...

Comment: well only one will run alone as the other depend of the queries within the WITH statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of speculation, but it is too long for a comment.  When getting long streams of error messages it is often helpful to look at the first one:

```
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Expr2522'.
```

Hmmm, that is curious, because there is no column called `expr2522` in your query.  This also looks like something that the SQL compiler would include in an execution plan.

My suspicion is that something changed in the database.  My advice is to recompile all your queries, stored procedures, functions, and views.  Recompiling will either fail and give you a more intelligible error message.  Or, it might adjust the queries and views to the new database structure so they will work.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds sensible, sadly the database I am working is too large for me to do that now. But i will investigate further

Answer (score 1):

Does the query reference any views in the database? If they were not created with schema binding, then its possible that the underlying database schema changed, invalidating the view.

It's also possible that the function ReportingFramework.dbo.fsCIS_CalculatePercentages has changed.

The short story is that the most likely cause is a change in the database schema or in a related function or procedure. You will need to pull the query apart and test it a section at a time to try and identify the part that is causing it to fail.

I would start with

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CoreProAchData
```

and see if that works, then build it up from there.